# Есть ли здесь уступительный союз и надо ли употреблять частицу «ни»?

Tags: частица, не-или-ни

> — Алексей, с какими бы мыслями вы **НЕ** пришли к Антонине,
> пожалуйста, не ругайте ее.

Здесь, вроде как, нет безусловного отрицания и нет усиления. Плюс подразумевается, что Алексей еще ни разу не приходил к Антонине. Однако я чисто интуитивно склоняюсь к варианту «ни» и не могу это объяснить.

Comment: *вроде как* — запятые не нужны.

Comment: Читал, что нередко применяется в художественной литературе как вводное слово, подчеркивающее неуверенность. Ну и по интонации обособил. Спасибо за заметку.

Comment: Это авторская пунктуация, не норма: https://i.imgur.com/EEV2wha.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Однако я чисто интуитивно склоняюсь к варианту «ни»

Поддерживаю.

Вот похожий пример (тоже "бы", придаточное и "какой"):
https://russkiymir.ru/education2/services/ask/145085
Там сказано, что придаточное уступительное. Здесь так же.

Всё подходит для употребления "ни". В придаточном есть частица "бы", а это характерный фактор.

Основным признаком является наличие и придаточного, и главного предложения (судя по пункту 5 Розенталя).

Правила здесь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82

Comment: Ссылка "russkiymir" открывает список всех вопросов, поэтому пришлось заходить по ней через сохраненную копию Google. В вопросе "russkiymir" четко видно, что ситуация уже определена ("Каким бы замечательным ни был..."), поэтому пример не подходит. У Розенталя тоже очень типичные примеры, где сразу понятно, какую частицу нужно использовать - это меня и путает. Давайте еще посмотрим, что предложат другие участники. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Просто там такая же структура, а время роли не играет. "Вы бы" подсказывает, что нужно "ни" (это не так ощущается из-за того, что "бы" стоит раньше). Можно придумать похожий пример: *Что вы бы ни решили, пожалуйста, не ругайте её.*

Comment: Отмечу ваш ответ решением вопроса. Спасибо.